# Find largest value in column which was before group by other column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to find largest oras_key grouped by acco_key.
So, if acco_key = 5, and occurs in oras_Key = (1,4,5,7), result should be oras_key=7, acco_key = 5 (largest oras_key).
That's one part of the problem.

Other part of the problem:
I have to find all those records - so largest oras_key, grouped by acco_key.
After that, sorting must be done by oras_key.

I've alreday tried grouping but I don't know how to find largest oras_key if I group by acco_key?

Here is table, data and desired output:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| oras_key | merc_key | acco_key |
+----------+----------+----------+
|        1 |        3 |        5 |
|        2 |        3 |        6 |
|        3 |        3 |        7 |
|        4 |        3 |        5 |
|        5 |        3 |        5 |
|        7 |        3 |        5 |
|        8 |        3 |        6 |
|        9 |        3 |        6 |
|       10 |        3 |        6 |
|       11 |        3 |        8 |
|       12 |        3 |        8 |
|       13 |        3 |        8 |
|       14 |        3 |        9 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Table definition and data:

```
 declare @tblTemp3 table
 (
 oras_key int,
 merc_key int,
 acco_key int
 )

 insert into @tblTemp3 (oras_key, merc_key, acco_key)
 values(1, 3, 5),
 (2, 3, 6),
 (3, 3, 7),
 (4, 3, 5),
 (5, 3, 5),
 (7, 3, 5),
 (8, 3, 6),
 (9, 3, 6),
 (10, 3, 6),
 (11, 3, 8),
 (12, 3, 8),
 (13, 3, 8),
 (14, 3, 9)
```

Desired output:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| oras_key | merc_key | acco_key |
+----------+----------+----------+
|       14 |        3 |        9 |
|       13 |        3 |        8 |
|       10 |        3 |        6 |
|        7 |        3 |        5 |
|        3 |        3 |        7 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select r = row_number() over (partition by acco_key order by oras_key desc)
         , *
    from @tblTemp3
)
select oras_key, merc_key, acco_key 
from cte 
where r = 1 
order by oras_key desc
```

However, seems like using the `MAX()` function would do too, if your `merc_key` is always the same:

```
select max(oras_key) oras_key, merc_key, acco_key
from @tblTemp3
group by acco_key, merc_key
order by oras_key desc
```

You can find a demo [here](http://rextester.com/YOBZ80971).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, it works. Perhaps you have a link to some good tutorial about the topic?

Comment: Hi! You could use the documentation for the [MAX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql) function and [this](http://mickeystuewe.com/2012/10/28/the-row_number-function-as-an-alternate-to-the-max-function/) article.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select max(oras_key) as oras_key,merc_key ,acco_key from @tblTemp3 group by 
 acco_key,merc_key
 order by 1 desc
```

Hope this is what you are looking for